# Вживання слова "казначейство" в українській мові

Tags: вживання-слів

В українській мові вживають два слова "казначейство" та "скарбниця" з однаковим значенням. Але чи властиве українській мові слово "казначейство"?

Якщо розглядати такий приклад як "державне казначейство", то мало б бути "державна скарбниця". При цьому чомусь спостерігається вживання обох словосполучень.

Тлумачення із СУМ слова *"скарбниця"* [(повне)](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F):

*СКАРБНИЦЯ, і, ж. 1. Урядова установа, яка відає державними коштами, державним майном.*

А ось [тлумачення слова *"казначейство"*](http://slovopedia.org.ua/38/53402/380354.html)

Слово "казначейство" потрапило в  українську мову через російське запозичення посередництвом тюркських мов.

То виходить, що вживання "державне казначейство" не властиве українській мові?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [академічних російсько-українських словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) слово *казначейство* перекладається як *скарбниця, скарбівниця, скарбовня*.

У [Словнику української мови у 20т.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=201591&page=1263) вже маємо *казначейство* у значенні скарбниця з поміткою застаріле і усталена назва державного органу:

> **КАЗНАЧЕ́ЙСТВО**, а, с. 1. заст. Те саме, що скарбни́ця
>
> 2. У сучасній Україні – офіційна назва державного фінансового органу, що забезпечує збір державних доходів і їх використання згідно з державним бюджетом, здійснює управління державним боргом, емісією білетів державної скарбниці та цінних паперів.

У [мовній консультації](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/51319/39-41-Turovska-Kazimiriva.pdf?sequence=1) знаходимо короткий підсумок:

> У сучасній українській мові функціонують фінансові терміни казначейство та
> скарбниця, засвідчені словниками з тотожним значенням. В
> офіційних державних документах надають перевагу запозиченому слову
> казначейство (СТП, с. 168), тоді як мовознавці наполягають на
> поверненні питомого терміна державна скарбниця, оскільки його
> фіксують авторитетні лексикографічні джерела (РУСНТ, с. 176; ТБ, с.
> 151; ЗВС, с. 202, 437)